# MS Access boolean validation rule. Check values from two different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables: Parameter and Measurement.
This is Parameter table:

```
     Param_id   Lspec   Uspec   LCL   UCL
         1       4.2     5.2    4.3   4.9
         2       3.2     4.2    3.3   3.8
         3       4.2     5.2    4.3   4.9
```

And this is Measurement table:

```
     Param_id   Value  Passed
         1       4.4    T/F
         2       3.5    T/F
         3       4.2    T/F
```

For Boolean column 'Passed' I need validation rule which is true when:

- (Lspec <= Value <= Uspec & LCL <= Value <= UCL)

How do I create such a validation rule?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. Field validation rules in tables can't span multiple tables and can't use lookup functions or user-defined functions, so it might be you're asking something which can't be done. However, you might use data macros for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
Select 
    Parameter.*,
    Measurement.*,
    (Lspec <= [Value] And [Value] <= Uspec And LCL <= [Value] And [Value] <= UCL) As Passed
From
    Parameter.*
Inner Join
    Measurement
    On (Parameter.Param_id = Measurement.Param_id)
```